# Input Attribute onChange only if Props is not Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using React with TypeScript, and I've created a Input Component which will take lots of Props, and many of them are optional. So far I've this.

```
interface InputProps {
    labelClassName?: string;
    labelName?: string;
    inputType: string;
    inputName?: string;
    inputValue: any;
    inputOnChange?: (e: any) => void;
    readOnly?: boolean;
}
```

Now, in the Input Component I want to render an label tag with an input inside. This input will inherit basically all the props, so I will have something like this.

```
export class Input extends React.Component<InputProps, {}> {
render() {
    console.log(this.props); 
    return (
        <label className={this.props.labelClassName}>
            {this.props.labelName}
            <input
                type={this.props.inputType}
                name={this.props.inputName}
                value={this.props.inputValue || ""}
                readOnly={this.props.readOnly}
                onChange={(e) => this.props.inputOnChange(e)} />
        </label>)
        ;
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I can't write the line with OnChange because TypeScript tell me "Object is possibly 'undefined'", which is totally true, since this.props.inputOnChange it's an optional props.

So, what I'd like to write it's something like "if this.props.inputOnChange(e) != undefined, then add onChange in the input", but... I don't know how do this.

I've tried the conditional rendering:

```
{this.props.inputOnChange &&
                onChange = {(e) => this.props.inputOnChange(e)} />
```

But it does not work

**EDIT:** One solution I did found it's to write something like this.

```
let inputOnChange = (this.props.inputOnChange != undefined)
        ? this.props.inputOnChange
        : undefined;

...

<input
    ...
    onChange={inputOnchange} />
```

But I honestly don't know if it's ok to pass an undefined to onChange

Comment: onChange={
(e) => { if (this.props.inputOnChange) {
this.props.inputOnChange(e) } } } />

Comment: That is completely fine.

Comment: My code ? Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you will want to handle `onChange` by providing your own function, and then conditionally propagating if the prop exists. Something like this:

```
export class Input extends React.Component<InputProps, {}> {

    handleOnChange = (e) => {
        if (this.props.inputOnChange) {
            this.props.inputOnChange(e);
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        const { labelClassName, labelName, inputType, inputName, 
                inputValue, readOnly } = this.props;

        return (
            <label className={labelClassName}>
                {labelName}
                <input
                    type={inputType}
                    name={inputName}
                    value={inputValue || ""}
                    readOnly={readOnly}
                    onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
            </label>
        );
    }
}
```

I'll give you one extra piece of advice, don't ever create an arrow function inside your `render` method if you can help it. For example:

```
<input onChange={(e) => something} />
```

The above creates a new function each time the `render` method is called. This will cause react to re-render the entire sub component tree because the function reference changed. In this case, it might not be a big deal, but if you had a large subtree of components you can run into performance issues relatively quickly.

Comment: You can create a option parameter and then initialize, additionally you can write some default code.

Answer (score 1):

You can include conditional props like this.

```
<input    
  {...this.props.inputOnChange && { onChange: this.props.inputOnChange }}
  // or
  {...this.props.inputOnChange && { onChange: (e) => this.props.inputOnChange(e, 'foo') }}
/>
```

Repeat for as many props as you need. This is just using the [Spread Attributes syntax](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html#spread-attributes) and you are not limited to just one spread or just one property in the object.

Meaning, this is all ok:

```
<input   
  {...props} // you already know this spread syntax 
  {...props && props} // spreads if defined
  {...a && { a }} // shorthand property name
  {...c && { c: (e) => c(e) }}
  {...x && { x, y:2, z:3 }} // multiple properties
/>
```

[Shorthand property names (ES2015)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Answer (score 0):

You can define `conditionalProps` object

```
let conditionalProps = {}

if (this.props.inputOnChange)
    conditionalProps["onChange"] = this.props.inputOnChange

// or with custom fn
if (this.props.inputOnChange)
    conditionalProps["onChange"] = (ev) => this.props.inputOnChange(ev, otherArgs)

return <input { ...conditionalProps} />
```

Alternatively

```
return (
  <XyzSomeOtherJSXMarkup>
    {this.props.inputOnChange
     ? <input onChange={this.props.inputOnchange} />
     : <input />}
  </XyzSomeOtherJSXMarkup>
)
```

Comment: I find this solution kinda elegant, but in the case of onChange, how could I pass the event argument? Or more arguments if needed?

Comment: For this you can use alternative option that I updated above.

Comment: @Jolly `conditionalProps["onChange"] = (ev) => this.props.inputOnChange(ev, otherArgs)`